# Creating a bug-free history in Git

Tags: git, debugging

Today I used `git bisect` successfully to track down the commit that introduced a bug.
When I descended into the bisections I noticed that there were actually two bugs, introduced in two separate commits. Now I like to fix one of the bugs and then use `git bisect` again in order to find the second bug. In order to do this I think I should fix the first bug such that the bug disappears in every stage of the history, right? That is, I should fix the commit that introduced the bug and then I should adapt every change that was applied to the buggy code. Only this way I can start a second bisection in order to hunt the second bug.

Is it possible to amend past commits such that git still knows that the commits are amendments of existing commits? Of course other developers should be able to pull in the bug fixes only and not a complete new history. That is, any solution that replaces old commits by ones with new hashes would not work.

Answer (score 0):

It is usually bad practice to rewrite history that has already been shared with other developers. You should probably make a new commit with your bugfix and push that rather that rewriting history.

That said, yes you can amend commits in the past. Let's say I want to change commit B here:

```
* 909debb (HEAD, master) C
* 5a12c7f B
* cfe7820 A
```

My favorite way to do that is with an interactive rebase.

```
% git rebase -i HEAD~2
```

This opens up an editor with the following:

```
pick 5a12c7f B
pick 909debb C
```

Change the `pick` to `edit` for the commit you want to change:

```
edit 5a12c7f B
pick 909debb C
```

Write the file.

```
% git rebase -i HEAD~2
Stopped at 5a12c7f... B
You can amend the commit now, with

        git commit --amend

Once you are satisfied with your changes, run

        git rebase --continue
```

Then make your changes:

```
% git add <files>
% git commit --amend -m 'Updated B'
% git rebase --continue
```

And now my history looks like this:

```
* bf4a3a7 (HEAD, master) C
* b79ab6f Updated B
* cfe7820 A
```

Comment: If I make a new commit with the bugfix and push it, then it will be far away in the history from the commit that introduced the bug. That is if I do another `git bisect` then this git bisect will jump around in the long phase where the bug was present. How can I move the bugfix commit next to the buggy commit and how can I tell `git bisect` not to try to select the buggy commit without the bugfix. Of course, adding a commit somewhere in history will not work, because subsequent commits are based on the buggy commit. How can I alter the affected commits as well?

Comment: In my example, I amended the commit that introduced the bug so that it looks like the bug never existed in the first place. If instead of `git commit --amend` I had done a `git commit` it would have added a commit right after the one that introduced the bug. But again, rewriting history is dangerous. It may be better to just live with the fact that there will sometimes be bugs in your history.

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind with git-bisect you can basically do anything before making a decision as to whether the tree is good or not.

As such, one solution that comes to mind is to use git-apply to manually apply a patch with the first fix (generated with git-diff, probably) to the working tree each time.

You might need to clean the patch out after each bisection with git reset --hard or similar.